# Validate a column if it contains a character, using check constraint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

Table:

```
create table tempchkconstraint ( 
  colcode varchar, 
  colname varchar, 
  lastmoddate timestamp without time zone 
);
```

Need to validate the column 'colcode' if any data with character '-' is trying to insert/update
Constraint added:

```
alter TABLE tempchkconstraint 
  add constraint chk_tempchkconstraint_code 
  check (colcode NOT ILIKE '%-%') ;
```

The constraint is working. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 1):

This condition should be equivalent, but faster:

```
strpos(colcode, '-') = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how you would do it to ensure that there is no string containing a '-' character. For the sake of completion, another way to do it would be to check via regex:

```
CHECK (colcode !~ '.*-.*')
```

This is overkill for single character checks, but allows more sophisticated checking.

Also, the constraint will throw an error to the application if it tries to insert a string containing '-', however, if you just want to filter the slashes out out, you could do so with a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION replace_slash() RETURNS trigger AS $replace_slash$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.colcode ILIKE '%-%' THEN
            NEW.colcode = replace(NEW.colcode,'-','');
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$replace_slash$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER no_slashes
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF colcode
ON tempchkconstraint
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION replace_slash();
```